# jQuery each() vs on()

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between these options?

## 1:

```
$('[data-focus-link]').each( function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $focus_id = $this.attr('data-focus-link');

  $this.click( function() {
    $('#' + $focus_id).focus();
  });

});
```

## 2:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-focus-link]', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $focus_id = $this.attr('data-focus-link');

  $('#' + $focus_id).focus();
  
});
```

Should I care what to use?

Comment: Simply use `$(document).on`? You should care what to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `$(document).on('click', '[data-focus-link]', function() { })` is better performance-wise, more noticeable if you have many items you want to listen for "click" event. It creates **only 1 event listener** on `document` and delegates the captured event to the element specified by the selector (eg.`[data-focus-link]`).

The `$('[data-focus-link]').each(function() {})` approach would create ***n* # of event listeners** with each one pointing a copy of the anonymous function you defined:

```
function() {
    $('#' + $focus_id).focus();
}
```

Go test it out and verify for yourself, try 10, 100, 1000, 10000 elements and you will see a dramatic drop in performance with the `.each()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you bind to **click**, then after removing element and readding it (or adding new ones) there will be no bind.

When you use **on**, it checks for all elements in parent (document), so there's no difference when you add elements.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that, in the first case, you are iterating over the elements that are already there in the DOM and without any user interaction.

In the second case, you do the same but, in a click event and you'll be iterating through the elements, including the dynamically added ones